# Modelio and Overture, does it work separately?

Tags: modelio, vdm++

So.. I’m trying to work with both Modelio and Overture but both programs is really new to me.

I want to make a model in Modelio as a first, and then export it to Overture.

But is it supposed to work this way, or am I supposed to make it separately?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you intend to use Modelio to create a Class Diagram with some classes and then export this diagram to EMF UML which can be imported in Overture. Overture will then create VDM classes matching the class defined in the class diagram.

> To convert a UML class diagram model to a VDM++ model, you first need to export the UML
>   model from Modelio to the Eclipse XMI format, called UML using the EMF UML3.0.0 format.
>   At the moment, Modelio is the only UML tool supported. In particular, the exported UML models
>   have been tested using Modelio 3.3.1.
>
> Exporting: Right-click a VDM++ or VDM-RT project to access a submenu for UML Transformation.
>   From here it is possible to Convert to UML. The resulting .uml file will be saved
>   to the generated folder of your project.
>
> Importing: To perform a UML import you must have the .uml file in the relevant project folder.
>   You can either copy it manually or use the Eclipse Import - File System feature. Afterwards,
>   it is possible to right-click the .uml file and choose the submenu for UML Transformation
>   and then select Convert to VDM

See the [Overture userguide](http://raw.github.com/overturetool/documentation/master/documentation/UserGuideOvertureIDE/OvertureIDEUserGuide.pdf) for further information

Comment: Hey Lausdahl. I don't know if this answers it all, but I figured out how to export from Overture and import an .umi to Modelio.

I can see my class and all that in the left side but I can't seem to get it to show my model. Can you help me with that?

Regards,
Kamilla

Comment: I guess you have to create a Class diagram and Drag&Drop your classes (on the left) into your diagram.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want to use both Modelio and Overture for vdmrt coding. 
In this case the ideal way to work would be to make a model in Modelio and then export it as vdmrt classes and use them in Overture as Modelio works with Eclipse/Java. Unfortunatly Mdoelio doesn not provide any generation/reverse facilities for vdmrt...

But Modelio and Overture can work together for CPS modelling. This is [INTO-CPS project](http://into-cps.au.dk/) aim. In this project, both Modelio and Overture provide [FMI](https://www.fmi-standard.org/) facilities which allow them to define CPS simulation. If you want more info please let me know.